# Youtube api v3 save video title

Tags: ruby, json, youtube-api

I want to use JSON to save a video's title given that I have the video ID (self.video_id). Right now I have:

```
require 'json'

    data = JSON.parse(open("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=#{self.video_id}&key=APIKEYw&fields=items(snippet(title))&part=snippet").read)
    name = data["items"][0]["snippet"]["title"]
```

I am getting the error:

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Comment: The problem is with the https connection. Does it work with only `http://` ? Or googleapis.com only allows https?

Comment: Use [`Net::HTTP#get`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS) for https.

Comment: It should work with https